# how to store open fire chat in custom DB table

Tags: php, mysql, openfire

I have started working on open-fire for making a chat web app. But I didn't know how to store all person to person chat in my database `chat` table.

Comment: I have tried 'ofarchive' table for store messages, but it not store person to person complete chat

Comment: you can use Open Archive plugin